# Centos server install Git and Gitolite After, Unable to connect via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, centos, gitolite

```
sh-3.2# ssh 115.2x.x.x
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
bash: /root/bin/gitolite-shell: No such file or directory
Connection to 115.2x.x.x closed.
```

"/etc/passwd" On Server:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it possible gitolite was installed with the `root` account.
The [gitolite doc](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#hu) mentions:

> When you install gitolite in ssh mode, you pick one specific user on the Unix system to be the "hosting user".
>   This is the user whose name goes into the repo URLs your users will be cloning, for example `ssh://git@server/repo`, or the simpler form `git@server:repo`.

Even in a [local installation (directly on the server)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#install), that setup should be done as a 'git' account, not as root.

Comment: This problem get. Remove git user account recreate git , git log into the system using the installation.